# Why can't I playback sound files recorded by AVAudioRecorder?

Tags: swift, swift2, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

This is how I defined myrecorder and myplayer

```
var myrecorder:AVAudioRecorder!
var myplayer : AVAudioPlayer!
```

This is the code to setup myrecorder in the viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    filepath = "\(getDocumentsDirectory())/001.caf"
    print(filepath)

    try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    //define settings
    let recordSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [
        AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue,
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
    ]
    myrecorder = try! AVAudioRecorder(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filepath), settings: recordSettings)
    myrecorder.delegate = self
    myrecorder.prepareToRecord()
}
```

And I have buttons to control record and stop and I got the file 001.caf. I can playback the sound file but I think the file is not good enough.

```
@IBAction func Play() {
    try! myplayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filepath))
    myplayer.volume = 0.5
    myplayer.play()
    print("Playing...")
}
```

The playback is successful without any error or crash. With only one problem, it doesn't have any sound when playing.

I assume that I'd missed something in the recording phase but I couldn't locate it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the AVAudioPlayer that is instantiated in this line.

```
try! myplayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filepath))
```

This instance myplayer will get deallocated as soon as the play function completes.

Instantiate the AVAudio player in another function, such as Viewdidload, so that it sticks around even after the control leaves the play function.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I have myplayer defind outside. Let me fix the question properly

Comment: And, btw, it doesn't make the instance permanent if you initiate it in the Viewdidload. To make the instance stick, you will have to define it outside of any particular method, which effectively make it stick to self. When self is there, the object is there. And also you can't put weak when define it. Where or when to initialize the instance doesn't matter.  I thought I didn't have to show define code because I didn't have LET before my instance name, that means I have defined it outside. It's all about the SCOPE of variable.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, finally I found the problem.

YOU CAN'T USE AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord.

When recording, you had to use AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord and when playback you use AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback. And you set the session back and forth when playback and record.

AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord is used when playback and recording are needed in the same time, like when you do voice chat...

Comment: Not so. Documentation on `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` says: "This category is appropriate for simultaneous recording and playback, _and also for apps that record and play back but not simultaneously_ [my italics]."

Comment: Try for yourself. I guess we can't really follow what the document says 100%. In my case, if I were using AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, then, I can't playback the CAF file I recorded. When I switch the type to be Playback when playing and Record when recording, everything works.

Comment: I notice in your code that you set the session category but you never _activate_ the session. That is much more likely to be the problem.